# Android: RCS ContentObserver permissions on Galaxy devices

Tags: android, permissions, galaxy, rich-communications-services

I am working on an Android application that registers a **ContentObserver** to listen for `MMS` and `SMS` messages. I am looking into doing the same for `RCS` so that the same functionality can be provided on **Galaxy** devices using `RCS` for messaging.
I seem to have found some valid [URIs](http://com.gsma.services.rcs.provider.chat/chatmessage).

However, whenever I try to access those URIs, I receive a `SecurityException` with the following message:

> Permission Denial: opening provider
>   com.sec.internal.tapi.service.provider.ChatProvider from ProcessRecord
>   requires com.gsma.services.permission.RCS or
>   com.sec.imsservice.WRITE_IMS_PERMISSION

I added both of the permissions mentioned above to the application's manifest and even attempted to request the permissions at runtime (although I was never prompted), but I am still getting the same `SecurityException`...

In addition to that, I came across the [documentation](https://www.gsma.com/futurenetworks/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/RCS-Device-API-1-5-spec-V2-0.pdf).

As suggested in section `4.4.5.5`, I attempted to add the following permissions, but again, with no success.

> CHATMESSAGE
>
> `4.4.5.5` Permissions Access to the Chat API requires the following permissions:
>
>  **com.gsma.services.rcs.RCS_USE_CHAT**: this is a new
>   permission that governs access to the chat API, and is required both
>   to receive and to send over an RCS chat session.
>
>  **com.gsma.services.rcs.RCS_READ_CHAT**: this is a new permission that is
>   required by a client in order to read the chat history from the
>   content provider.

Has anyone had any success accessing `RCS` data? If so, how were you able to access it?

Alternatively, does anyone know if it is even possible for third-party applications to access that data? Thanks!

Comment: Same problem... did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

No, RCS is currently not supported for 3rd-party applications an Android just yet. The only app that currently utilizes RCS is the Android Messages app on supported carriers.

I believe an update to the Carrier Services app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.ims will allow developers the tools to utilize the features.